# Raphael arrow heads not shown up in pdf

Tags: raphael, batik, export-to-pdf

I am creating a chart using raphael.js. In my chart there are rectangles which are connected using arrows. I am exporting this svg using [Raphael Export](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export) and then converting this svg string to pdf using batik. But in the pdf i am not getting the **arrowheads** at the connectors connecting the various rectangles in the pdf. I am using raphael [graffle](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) for creating connection between rectangles. 
I really need those arrows in the pdf. Please let me know what could be the issue.

Also adding defs tag statically and replacing the arrow-head attribute with marker-end-url by manipulating the svg string doesn't looks like a good solution.Is there any other way of doing it.?

Comment: maybe show a DEMO code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Here is fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/nHEsE/10/ . I forgot to mentions that the graffle connections method has been modified to show the arrowheads. I found the modification on stackoverflow itself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have found the issue.
It seems like the issue is with the defs tag(that contains the marker ids)  of raphael are not included in exported svg and also marker-end-url attribute is not present in the path elements because of which arrow-heads are not showing. 
In path elements of rapahel, while export, instead of marker id another attribute is added which is "arrow-end": "classic-midium-midium". So when i added the defs tag of raphael into my generated svg and replace the arrow-end attribute with the marker-end-url attribute by giving the required value the arrow heads appeared. 
But now the issue is with the positioning of arrow heads. In the exported svg the x and y coordinates of horizontal and vertical arrowheads is slightly more which leads to intersection of arrows with the object(rectangles in my case) which doesn't look good. But yes for now i am going with it.I have modify raphael.export.js. So for any one who looking for solution  have to add following  2 lines of code in raphael.export.js

1.In R.fn.toSVG function add following after initialization of svg variable at line number 217
`You have to append defs tag  of raphael to svg variable here. Not able to post here.`

2.In the serializer variable where the tag for path is creatd add following line at line number 199
`initial['marker-end'] = "url(#raphael-marker-endclassic33)";`

Thanks